# String can't display in second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I was trying to display user input and password in second activity but I got an error unfortunatly login has stopped...
I am getting an error java.lang.nullpointerException : attempt to invoke virtual method'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.ChaeSequence)' on a null object reference.

Main class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{

    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
            String userStr = userName.getText().toString();
            String passStr = password.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondAcivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userName", userStr);
            intent.putExtra("password", passStr);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Second Class.

```
public class SecondAcivity extends MainActivity
{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_acivity);

             TextView  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
             Intent intent = getIntent();
             String  userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName");
             String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
             textView.setText("User Name: " + userName + " Password: " + password);


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });


    }
```

Comment: post your error log too

Comment: and the exception you get is?

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important information - what error did you actually get.

Comment: Java.lang.Null pointer excetion

Comment: in what statement did the error point?

Answer (score 2):

You dont pull the strings from the instance of `Intent` itself. You need to fetch the `Bundle` of extras from the Intent and then get strings from the `Bundle`:

**Use this:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

String userName = "";
String password = "";

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("userName");
    password = extras.getString("password");
}
```

Comment: Thanx but problem is in XML

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the NullPointerException when empty values are passed
 
Try :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String userName,password;

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("userName");
    password = extras.getString("password");
}
```

Comment: This will still not handle NPE, if the extras are missing, as the declared string variables have not been iniliazed and you are simply skipping assignment. They are still null when you try to use them later. Updated my answer with the correct way. Pl check

Comment: this will display only NEWTEXT not userName and password

Answer (score 0):

kindly check in your **R.layout.activity_second_acivity** if the id **textView** exists. The texview variable will become null if the R.id.textView does not exist in your R.layout.activity_second_acivity.

Comment: Can u please tell me when i start activity after closing it will display me previous userName and Password

Answer (score 0):

Your attempting to set text to null TextView

check if  second activity layout file `activity_second_acivity`
contains `textView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get string from activity

```
String userName,password;
userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userName");
password = getIntent().getExtras().getString("passowrd");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String userName,password;


if (getIntent().hasExtra("userName")) {
    userName = extras.getString("userName");
    password = extras.getString("password");  
        }
```

Comment: you should write some explanation too.